# Is it possible to build a python based HTML scraper that returns the current highest buy order on the Steam marketplace?

Tags: python, steam

Using the [AK redline page](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29) as an example, I'm trying to get the value under listings where it says "20000 requests to buy at $X.XX or lower". I have the framework of the HTML scraper in python(using Beautiful Soup) but due to my lack of HTML knowledge I'm pretty lost trying to get this number, even after spending a good hour going through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I'm dumb. I just had to inspect element on the buy order then use that span class for soup.